# Glassfish 3/EJB 3. Standalone java client

Tags: glassfish, client, ejb, javabeans

i'm developing an application on top of netbeans API using Glassfish 3.1.2. My netbeans application is supposed to be my standalone java client that have to connect to the EJB.

I have packaged my EJB into an EAR (enterprise application). The problem i'm facing of is that i got an exception when i try to lookup for available EJBs.

Here is my bean session:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = "java:global/AltServer", beanInterface = AltServerRemote.class)
public class AltServer implements AltServerRemote {
```

The remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface AltServerRemote {
```

And finally the lookup call:

```
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", getGlassfishHostname());
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", getServerPort());
ctx = new InitialContext(props)

ctx.lookup("java:global/AltServerEnt/AltServer-ejb/AltServer")
```

About how to lookup an EJB packaged into an EAR, i have followed this : http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#CosNaming and foud the jndi syntax:

```
java:global[/<app-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>
```

So in my case my enterprise application is **AltServerEnt**, my EJB module is **AltServer-ejb** and my session bean is called **AltServer** (see above).

Note: I have used the @EJB annotation to my session bean to specify a name like explained in FAQ i linked above, i'm not sure it's suitable when the EJB is part of an EAR. Anyone know?

And here the exception i got, raised at the line of the lookup:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ejb.codegen.GenericEJBHome_Generated
```

There are a lot of "Caused" clauses but here is the first one:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/AltServerEnt/AltServer-ejb/AltServer' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=127.0.0.1, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfaceorg.altanis.remote.AltServerRemote [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke defineClass!]]
```

So i guess my session bean is not found but why? My JNDI syntax isn't right?

EDIT: Just to notice my project organization:

- AltServerEnt: Enterprise Application - contains the EJB module
- AltServer-ejb: EJB Module - contains the sessions bean and includes a netbeans plugin that contains the remote interface (AltServerRemote).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EAR/EJB apparently deployed.  So bring up the Glassfish Admin console, something like `https://<host>:4848` and login.  On the left, navigate through `Applications` and click on your application to bring up the 'Edit Application' screen.  Examine Application's name & Component names displayed - and compare to what your expectations are.

I don't have any remote EJBs deployed at the moment, so I can't confirm - but I think that for remote EJBs there may be a link under the `Action` column to display the URL.

#### Naming Options

1. Use the name `AltServer` as the EJB's name: `name="EJB(name = "AltServer" ...)`.  With a "simple name", the bean can be found in various JNDI namespaces (global/app/module); your lookup `ctx.lookup("java:global/AltServerEnt/AltServer-ejb/AltServer")` should work.
2. If you add the prefix `java:global` then you've declared a name directly in the JNDI global namespace; you would be able to lookup your bean directly in that namespace using the same name: `java:global/AltServer`.  Yes, you should still be able to access it in other namespaces - see first paragraph.

#### Also

You ask: "I have used the @EJB annotation to my session bean to specify a name like explained in FAQ i linked above, i'm not sure it's suitable when the EJB is part of an EAR. Anyone know?"

It's fine, it all depends on what you want.  Like all name-spaces, one might think towards avoiding overpopulating a namespace - particularly the global namespace.  Give it a few moments of thought, and just make a decision - and be ready to rethink it if needed :-)

Comment: Thanks. I have made some arrangements in my jndi syntaxes and i got some CommunicationException that i solved by including the app server-rt jar file in my client. It seems to work right now :)